# rdrop2 shinyapp working locally but wont deploy to shinyapps.io due to startup taking too long, followed various advice still cant get it too work

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, rdrop2

I am trying to get a shinyapp which uses persistent data storage through drop box to deploy to shinyapps.io. The app works locally however when I deploy it, it says *An error has occurred Unable to connect to worker after 60.00 seconds; startup took too long*.

I have tried changing the token part at the top in various ways but cant get it to deploy despite the fact the deployment is complete and the log shows no errors I can see. (see below)

```
----- Deployment log started at  2020-06-13 14:01:48  -----
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/R/WHUAAPP3", appFileManifest = "C:/Users/Clare/AppData/Local/Temp/18ff-4edc-f7e3-ddae",      account = "clareb1992", server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "WHUAAPP3",      appId = 2449618, launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE),      logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1   rsconnect_0.8.15
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
GET /v1/applications/2449618 499ms
----- Bundle upload started at  2020-06-13 14:01:48  -----
[2020-06-13 14:01:48] Inferring App mode and parameters 
[2020-06-13 14:01:48] Bundling app dir 
[2020-06-13 14:01:48] Generate manifest.json 
[2020-06-13 14:02:19] Writing Rmd index if necessary 
[2020-06-13 14:02:19] Compressing the bundle 
POST /v1/bundles 530ms
[2020-06-13 14:02:20] Starting upload now 
PUT /bundles/application-2449618/0b31cdcbc7da417c910efe4c49bb3eb1.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA54P7SCTKV2M6JLF2&x-amz-acl=bucket-owner-full-control&Expires=1592056940&content-md5=b8Dnuby4YQfhUxgS5Gt8JQ%3D%3D&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEPr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIHfSe75nt1MhoLjRJ%2Fm4JTO0h0DfE4RqV%2B0fWwScfhWaAiEA0af1UvQ5L5QZvQItLRCr8lFkMMvYHXItsCtBLZZbATcqtAMIcxAAGgw5NTQ1NTU1NjkzNjUiDDkEtK8%2By0IIVyr6uyqRA90FDB5OTTY36udZsdWTicdKOqhtq6dDQJCGooHdm9gVGo0vqpdKD9Y7ISkFw1Re4Hw0vhQlXT9wVhMA4wrjcldzfKbOpwTyDfe44dJDs032LMDJPcTgavsu2mZ1jUwlQhpX80KzKAwnlFhlJDBGH8Y0Tjo6PIkqj%2FUbWfh3HaNpwlEuIuM3tUJwMuXbyQLMlMhC52slbqnWvbm4W4RVjBWlxjLqJpNwOojhVXjB4sX7qAm2iUKUJH9Awzxz9Uz%2F7QBeAIBIsJYtcvJvKwT12d9I1QyF58wapgbl3mJT%2Ftmc7bs0ZNhzHCuP6H6ujjF49w9AJquIk5HJtb%2BgNdZOZ%2BtnTlYskzELYXsVuPtpg6mXswUhOOPYGzP4rnFBR7p5wbKmcXeOFKvIp74Hk0b3U0XSxJ4Rw8jBkbxiZfDN18hCK%2FX04zmBeBPUEQUhysUHe%2BMEyeJysx8QlHGredyLzptx015vPD1J1ExKseoIBjayc4qLH%2B6xwrdFbDJ3rEj%2BoFWAtOdwpUUcAPmXoDCrJdMgMPO6kvcFOusBul%2B9425fsIpS5QwvsOHhiFKIe8K8OPlZ3%2FDIo8yb551x3XpO%2BJR%2B5l0sJ3XIKBkHfgjHLUheNh13w7bE6ya3taZxJw5yuL%2FXMGlaGABbuJ3BoMoeyeOte8REL%2F1X027jcNS7AapISwxsQgT6pc4zNY8JV6MZt16vfwDZvVuOPjXF2VTfSbsLZnUUMBOok5uk37fx9r%2F7blBqVDASoO%2Fy5pBo8FaUKhQYcbFMjpOJc15jz3hXrpAjTwEcA8LpZnBY5PlKUdPK5SCMjaHRE9Vd7gXg%2FrfKQJ86xBW5wYLaF3jFXZjVyUzwlncuTg%3D%3D&Signature=cW1teEVyFR%2Bl4Q8X4IlygH51ysE%3D&content-type=application%2Fx-tar 1079ms
[2020-06-13 14:02:21] Upload complete 
POST /v1/bundles/3265302/status 509ms
GET /v1/bundles/3265302 450ms
[2020-06-13 14:02:22] Saving deployment record for WHUAAPP3 -  
----- Server deployment started at  2020-06-13 14:02:22  -----
POST /v1/applications/2449618/deploy 579ms
Waiting for task: 746557269
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 449ms
  building: Processing bundle: 3265302
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 500ms
  building: Building image: 3654460
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 490ms
  building: Fetching packages
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 520ms
  building: Installing packages
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 460ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 670ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 490ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 500ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 479ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 490ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 480ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 470ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 500ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 519ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 579ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 570ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 480ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
  building: Installing files
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 500ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 450ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 480ms
  building: Pushing image: 3654460
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 459ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 520ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 480ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 450ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 450ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 520ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 500ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 480ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 480ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 450ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 459ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 460ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 449ms
  deploying: Starting instances
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 469ms
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 500ms
  rollforward: Activating new instances
GET /v1/tasks/746557269 459ms
  success: Stopping old instances
----- Deployment log finished at  2020-06-13 14:03:35  -----
Deployment completed: https://clareb1992.shinyapps.io/WHUAAPP3/
```

Current Code

Here is the minimal code I am using any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rdrop2)
library(DT)
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp

token <- drop_auth()
saveRDS(token, "my-token.rds")
drop_auth(rdstoken = "my-token.rds")

outputDir <- "Games"

fields <-  
  c("Date","Umpire","UIN","Level","HomeTeam","AwayTeam","Coach","Assessor", 
   "Assessment","Good1","Good2","Bad1","Bad2","FurtherN")
    
    
    title<-tags$b(tags$img(src="WHUA_Logo.jpg",width=50, height=50),'WHUA Umpiring Game Tracker and 
     Reflection App')
    
    ui <-dashboardPage(skin= "yellow", #this gives the main app background colour
                       dashboardHeader(
                         title = title, titleWidth = 700),
    
    ## all mydashboard stuff
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      
      saveData <- function(data) {
        data <- t(data)
        # Create a unique file name
        fileName <- sprintf("WHUAAppData3.csv", as.integer(Sys.time()), digest::digest(data))
        # Write the data to a temporary file locally
        filePath <- file.path(tempdir(), fileName)
        write.csv(data, filePath, row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
        # Upload the file to Dropbox
        drop_upload(filePath, path = outputDir)
      }
      
      loadData <- function() {
        
        filesInfo <- drop_dir(outputDir)
        filePaths <- filesInfo$path_display
        data <- lapply(filePaths, drop_read_csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
        data <- do.call(rbind, data)
        data
      }
      
      
      # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
      #formData is a reactive function
      formData <- reactive({
        data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
        data
      })
      
      # When the Save button is clicked, save the form data
      observeEvent(input$save,{
        saveData(formData())
      })
      
      # Show the previous responses
      # (update with current response when save is clicked)
      output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
        input$save
        loadData()
      })   
      
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

```
````

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was overcomplication.

```
token <- drop_auth()
saveRDS(token, "my-token.rds")
```

These lines of code only need to be run once and then they need to be removed from the global environment to make the app deployment work you only want

```
drop_auth(rdstoken = "my-token.rds")
```

in your global environment. Hopefully this helps others in the future.